# How Does the Reward Model in ChatGPT Calculate Losses?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, loss-function, language-model, ranking, loss

Reading the InstructGPT paper(which seems to be what ChatGPT was built off of), I found this equation for the reward function. [image]

However, I'm struggling to understand how this equation is used to translate rankings between different response to a scalar.

For example, if I have four generated responses, A, B, C, and D, and with D being the best response, with D>C>B>A, then how is the loss calculated? How are relative scores converted to absolute losses.